# Codeigniter get row

Tags: codeigniter

I use codeigniter for my website, but I have a problem I have done script who returns rows from different tables. But it write me error **Trying to get property of non-object**. This is my code. Where is a problem?

```
      $this->db->select('*');
      $this->db->from('orders');
      $this->db->where('order_id',$order_id);
      $array_keys_values = $this->db->get();
      $row = $array_keys_values->row();

      $this->db->select('*');
      $this->db->from('pacients');
      $this->db->where('pacient_account_id',$row->order_pacient_id);
      $array_keys_values2 = $this->db->get();
      $row2 = $array_keys_values2->row();

      $this->db->select('*');
      $this->db->from('doctors');
      $this->db->where('doctor_account_id',$doctor_id);
      $array_keys_values3 = $this->db->get();
      $row3 = $array_keys_values3->row();
```

Comment: This is error http://i45.tinypic.com/2lwuqt3.jpg

Comment: Do you have `db_debug` enabled in your database configuration? Seems like the `$this->db->get()` returns false and that might mean the generated query is invalid (no such table/column) or such.

Comment: Yes I have db_debug set on TRUE. But my query is ok.

Comment: The reason you're getting that error is because the result is returned as a two-dimensional array and not an object. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13110943/463139) below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('orders');
$this->db->where('order_id',$order_id);
$array_keys_values = $this->db->get();    
if ($array_keys_values->num_rows() > 0) {
    foreach ($array_keys_values->result() as $row) {
       // now you can work with $row
    }
}

$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('pacients');
$this->db->where('pacient_account_id',$row->order_pacient_id);
$array_keys_values2 = $this->db->get();
if ($array_keys_values2->num_rows() > 0) {
    foreach ($array_keys_values2->result() as $row2) {
        // now you can work with $row2
    }
}

$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('doctors');
$this->db->where('doctor_account_id',$doctor_id);
$array_keys_values3 = $this->db->get();
if ($array_keys_values3->num_rows() > 0) {
    foreach ($array_keys_values3->result() as $row3) {
        // now you can work with $row3
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No row was returned. Use an if statement with a num_rows() > 0 to check